# Is it possible to record a range of radio frequencies in one go?

Tags: radio, electromagnetism

I am wondering if the following is theoretically possible:

The device can record say 1 hour of electromagnetic wave/radio signals today, and in the future recreate/replay that, so people can listen to 1 hour of historical radio show and **freely change radio channels** (like from FM100 to FM96), even to frequencies with only noise.

I don't want to record channels individually, but use one receiver to receive a range of frequencies.

Comment: SDR (Software Defined Radio) may be able to achieve this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got two options: wideband or baseband.

## Wideband

The "simple to describe but hard to build" way is to just capture the data outright and record it. The limits are bandwidth and dynamic range.

### Bandwidth

For wideband, you'll need to sample at a rate of over twice your highest frequency. Considering the US FM radio band, which extends from 88 to 108 MHz, you'll need to sample at over 216 Msample/s. It's going to be very hard to find an ADC that can sample more than about 14 or 16 bits at that rate.

Also, data storage will be tough: at 16 bits/sample, you're generating 432 MB/s (3456 Mb/s or 3.37 Gb/s) of data. Note that this is faster than the peak (unrealistic) 3.0 Gb/s of SATA II and only achievable with highly tuned RAID 0 arrays or flash drives. One hour (3600 seconds) requires about 2 TB of storage.

### Dynamic Range

Since each channel is generated by a different transmitter, the received signal strength will be different for each. Since you don't want a receiver-per-channel system, then your receiver has to set its gain to ensure that the closest (strongest) station does not drown out the others.

Since 16 bits is only 96 dB or so, and signal strength drops something like 6 dB per range doubling (r^-2), not counting path losses such as rain or intervening structures.  Distant stations will be received with less resolution.

## Baseband

The other option is to shift the band (i.e. heterodyne) to a lower band so the total bandwidth isn't so bad.

### Bandwidth

I'd recommend what is called a "Low-IF" system, where the band is shifted down close to but not quite to 0 (DC). This allows you to keep a DC blocking filter (and maybe even a 60 Hz power line filter) which will help reduce interference and circuit errors such as offset voltages.

So, for example, you shift the 20 MHz of bandwidth between 88-108 MHz down to around 3-23 MHz. This lets you sample at 50 MHz, which might let you find an 18 bit ADC, adding about 12 dB to dynamic range... still not much.

## What You Lose

A typical FM radio receiver has several stages that you have to throw away in order to receive the entire band:

- A tuner that selects the desired channel
- A channel filter that strongly rejects interference from other channels. This filter allows high fidelity even with low-dynamic range ADCs such as 8 or 10-bit models.
- An automatic gain control circuit that sets the receiver gain based on the received signal level, maximizing usage of the available dynamic range
- A much smaller bandwidth (200 kHz) that you must decode
- Multiple-stage heterodyne structures that let you filter the channel more than once. For example, most radios bandshift the selected channel down to a center frequency of 10.7 MHz, then filter it with a high-precision ceramic-resonator filter, then bandshift it down to 455 kHz and filter it again before creating a quadrature channel and detecting the signal.
- Better control of frequencies, so that the signal from one stage doesn't create a false signal in another.

So, in conclusion, while what you ask for is not impossible, there are several things about it that will compromise performance to the point of making it nearly useless.

Comment: SDR stuff addresses most of the steps you're referring to. And if the signal is captured in quadrature, he can halve the sampling rate of the ADC's, which should permit the use of higher resolution ADC's.

Comment: Halving the sampling rate with quadrature will buy you a bit or two in resolution, significantly increases power consumption and parts count, and it does *nothing* to reduce the data rate (samples are two-element vectors instead of scalars). And yes, I wrote the answer with SDR (software-defined radio) in mind; I wrote [a tutorial on SDR](https://hostdb.ece.utexas.edu/~wireless/ee381K_spring09/reports/desimone.pdf) two years ago for a class that may be of interest.

Comment: Generally high performance ADCs are used singly rather than in quadrature as the circuit cost becomes substantial.  Zero-IF Quadrature is then generated digitally by a computational IQ mixer.  Note that a narrowing bandwidth can increase effective resolution, so in practice 14 to 16 bits at 100 or so MSPS is usually enough for impressive dynamic range.  Unfortunately, the same processing gain is _not_ found on the transmit/reconstruction side, and raw DAC performance may also be worse than ADC performance.

Answer (score 5):

This is somewhat like what radio astronomers do.  Different kinds of information are available in different frequency ranges.  There are narrow spectral lines carrying information about atoms, temperatures, magnetic fields, and everything changes over time.  Intensities plotted over several octaves of frequency tell about synchrotron radiation, thermal sources, dust clouds and so on.  A neutron star specialist might want to know about changes in intensity and doppler shifts of the fastest-spinning pulsars on a time scale of milliseconds. Astrochemists may want very finely spaced frequencies to capture details of distant molecular clouds.

No way can current Earthling technology gather all the wave data so finely over frequency and time, for say an hour, to do all of these kinds of research in post-observation analysis.  Each scientist must decide and ask for the system to be configured one way or another for what each wants.

One of the most important parts of the system to configure is the correlator.   I worked at NRAO for a while.  They gather tons of data per day.   At EVLA (formerly VLA, now improved) they gather the signal from 27 dishes.  And in two polarizations - you didn't ask about that!  What EVLA can do is described at https://science.nrao.edu/facilities/evla/capspec

But what makes it possible for us mere 21st Century humans is that radio astronomers do their work on the phase differences of the signals - being pretty much just noise, it's a statistical correlation done in FPGAs. Super-fast FFTs, 1-bit, 2-bit or if they have the money 3-bit ADCs.  (So rare to see ADCs with so few bits anywhere but in high energy physics and radio astronomy!)  The information content in the EM waves at the receivers is way chopped down to what scientists find still useful.  Of course the astronomers are not recreating Rush Limbaugh or yesterday's baseball game, but making images, data points to fit theoretical curves to, etc.

If you have the funding and equipment and wanted to record, let's say, the FM broadcast band as received at some point in the USA for one hour, sure it's doable, but way beyond average hobbyist capabilities.  But compared to most radio astronomy facilities, it would be a piece of cake, aside from the fact that radio astronomers don't build equipment for frequency ranges polluted by broadcast.  For sure you'll want to down-convert.  88MHz - 108 MHz to 0MHz - 10MHz, which Nyquist says to sample at 20MHz. For one hour that's 72 billion samples.  Bah, easy...

The PDF at https://science.nrao.edu/facilities/alma/naasc-memo-series/naasc-memos/104.interferometry-basics/view might make a good read.  Also, about the EVLA correlator and the amounts of data it has to crank through, https://mitr.drao.nrc.ca/widar/index.shtml The data that the astronomers get is analyzed using CASA software, which being publicly funded any electronics geek is welcome to download, but expect a steep learning curve (even for astrophysics students) - see http://casa.nrao.edu/

Answer (score 3):

This is what *software-defined radio* (SDR) is about.

Simply put, it means that you hook an antenna to the input of a very fast ADC, and then you do the processing of the received data in your processor or FPGA, etc.

[Wikipedia article about software-defined radio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio)

Comment: You still need a low-noise amplifier and some filtering between the antenna and the ADC(s). Also, since the filtering is by design wideband, it is much less effective at rejecting interference than a simpler, narrowband, channel-selecting front end.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's theoretically possible, BUT the bandwidth needed is as large as the range of frequencies that you wish to record.

For the FM audio channels that you suggest it's probably actually doable. For the whole FM band or for video channels the bandwidth needed becomes large. 
So, for practical purposes it would be impractical over more than a very limited channel range.

You'd probably achieve this by effectively producing a wideband superhet receiver and converting the band of interest down to baseband and recording it. Or, if you had a recorder dedicated to recording a certain bandwidth you could adjust it accordingly.

Nomenclature varies somewhat but by FM96 to FM100 you probably mean 96 to 100 Mhz or 4 MHz bandwidth. This is in the order of bandwidth available from a domestic TV tape recorder eg VHS or Beta **but** these are very much tailored to the characteristics of the TV signal and may well not be easily adapted to this use.

Digital storage would be feasible but probably expensive. Maybe not. I haven't thought this through but a 4 MHz bandwidth may be able to be recorded in say about 8 MB/second or about 32 GB/hour. That's affordable given the capability it provides.

[Wikipedia - FM broadcasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_broadcasting)

[Wikipedia - FM broadcast band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_broadcast_band)

[FCC frequency allocations](http://www.panix.com/clay/scanning/frequencies.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easy to record a collage of different radio frequencies using s specially designed microphone to pick up high radio frequencies..  But it won't play back through a normal recorder with an output transformer and speaker designed to omit sound waves.  It would need to be a digital recording and for play back those digital frequency recordings would need to be sent through an encompassing radio transmitter to then discriminate the different channels through a common A.M or F.M. radio. Of course the transmitter and radio would need to be in some type of Farady cage to block any other live radio signals from coming in.